# webkit-animatoin hanging in mid-air

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've a a webkit-animation code that makes a ball bounces up and down on hover, 
problem is when cursor is not tailing the ball it hangs in mid-air, so basically you have to follow the ball up and down for it to work.
What I need is for the ball to bounce by itself as soon as the cursor touches it.

here's the code:

```css
    .animated { 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
        animation-duration: 1s; 
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
        animation-fill-mode: both; 
        animation-play-state: paused; 
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; 

    } 



    .animated:hover{
       animation-play-state: running; 
    }

@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);} 
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);} 
} 

@keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {transform: translateY(-30px);} 
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);} 
} 

.bounce { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce; 
    animation-name: bounce; 
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining the actual animation it's using?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an actual animation on this

see here -- https://jsfiddle.net/9tvwkvdc/2/

I just added the pulse for example and added (Change it to whatever you want of course)

```
  animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
```

Also - make sure you use all the appropriate vendor prefixes.

You can condense some of what you have by doing stuff like this -

```
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite both paused; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    pulse 1s infinite both paused; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      pulse 1s infinite both paused; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:  pulse 5s infinite both paused;
```

Comment: yeah dude i just added the rest of the animation, it works fine but have to follow the ball all the way, i just want to hover over it and it bounces then returns to original position by itself.

Comment: @ابوخلود Then don't pause the animation, just run it when you mouse over it, and have the animation itself return to origin state at 0%, or don't use forwards and it will snap back to the original position.

Comment: the Fiddle you added explains perfectly, try hovering really quick over "test", you notice it stays where it is, i need it to smoothly animate back to original place.

Comment: @ابوخلود I would suggest you look into something like jquery for that if you look here https://jsfiddle.net/9tvwkvdc/6/ .With this example your mouse does not have to follow the item. Jquery/Javascript have some stuff to let you deal with the scenario you are looking for, but as soon as you take the hover class off it will return to it's original state, and css has no way of calculating the difference to animate back smoothly.

Comment: hmm i tried that, now it bounces before you even hover. also tried adding hover to parent div to pause it, didnt work dammit -_-"

Comment: @ابوخلود for the effect you are looking for you will need javascript, i would recommend jquery.

Comment: duude i figured it out! all you have to do is put the animation code in the hover itself! with a animation-delay to make it more realistic it's almost perfect! thanks alot bro totally appreciate the help man.

Comment: @ابوخلود yeah that's what I was showing you in my example a few comments before :) https://jsfiddle.net/9tvwkvdc/6/ . Glad I could help. don't forget to vote if it was helpful.